# Remote access to MySQL - UNSAFE?

Tags: mysql, security, connection

Is it unsafe to open the mysql server port to allow remote connections? 
If it is unsafe, what is a better solution?

EDIT:

-I need read and write rights. 
-Each user has a password to connect. That means that not any user can connect to the database.

What security problems does this enviroment have? 
Is there a better solution?

Comment: As long as the users have read only rights I dont think it is unsafe.!!!

Comment: they must have both read and write rights... why is it unsafe then?

Comment: If you have provided all the rights to the user then it may be that any user can drop the table which he/she should not do!!! Rest I dont think there is any issue!!!

Comment: By opening it to remote connections, you expose it to the risks of the remote users' passwords being lost or brute-forced, or the service being DDOS'd.  Be very cautious with this, and if you must allow remote access, do it with proper host-based authentication wherever possible.  Don't allow any user access from any host.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting the idea. Plese read my edit.

Comment: With any network service or firewall implementation, you should be thinking about this in terms of denying all access by default, and opening access only as necessary in as limited a manner as you can achieve.

Comment: What Michael says. It is generally regarded not a good idea and mySQL has had security problems in the past. That's why most all hosting providers don't allow access from outside.

Comment: Related: [How can I connect to MySQL remotely and still keep it safe?](http://serverfault.com/q/363711)

Comment: Ok. So, what is a better solution to allow users for remote access to the database?

Comment: @user2471107 The safest is to use the SSH tunneling as described in Pekka's link from serverfault, if you have shell access to the MySQL server and can provide shell accounts to the users who need them. Then, they are connecting via a secure SSH connection and MySQL itself is not actually exposed to the outside but from the client it appears it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, MySQL has a rigorous permissions system which could be set up to allow remote users minimal levels of access to the tables they would need to do their job.

In practice, MySQL has had many exploits in the past, both in applying those permissions and in preventing access to the host server. It is reasonable to expect more in future; since very few admins allow untrusted access to a MySQL server, it is not strongly locked down against attacks (unlike, say, a web server like Apache).

MySQL's authentication model is also weak: passwords are stored in a table as unsalted hashes and there is no protection against brute-force password attacks. For communication between a trusted server app and the DB, you can get away with that; for authentication of not-wholly-trusted third parties it's not good enough.

If your “users” are database administrators, it's plausible to give them remote access, with access locked down by IP address/firewall or SSH tunnel. If the “users” are not-fully-trusted third parties you expect to be using the database as part of a client application, I wouldn't. And definitely don't open access to the whole public internet.

In any case, if we are talking about application users, your business rules are going to need more granularity in access rights than you can manage with table- or column-level controls. For example rules like “reviewer-class users may set article.state to 3 but only if article.state was previously 1 or 2”, or “setting article.state to 4 always causes the associated articlecontent to be deleted” cannot be reproduced in table permissions.

For that, you almost always need some component between the raw table storage and the remote client/application to manage the requests. That layer is traditionally a separate server application which is the only thing talking to the database. You could in theory write that component in database stored procedures, and give users access only to the procs not the tables. But doing anything complicated in stored procs is a super pain to write and maintain compared to a general-purpose programming language.